# Cassini: difference between trajectory and orbital trim maneuvers in this list?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, cassini

I found this site with quite a substantial amount of data, tabulations, and more for many space exploration missions. There are detailed information on the Cassini mission here:

http://www.dmuller.net/spaceflight/mission.php?mission=cassini

From the start until May 2008, event descriptions that include the word maneuvre (maneuver) is found only as "Trajectory maneuvre", and they are numbered 1 through 157 in June 2008. However after that, they are labeled "Orbital trim maneuvre" and numbered OTM-164 to OTM-255. After 2010 there are no maneuvers listed at all, although the detailed list of events continues into the future - probably end of mission.

Is there an official distinction here between Trajectory and Orbital trim maneuvers, or is this just the language used for this particular site. Is there an official list of maneuvers beyond 2010 somewhere else that I could look at?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about the first part of your question, however NASA's Eyes program should have a list of all the manuevers. I know that Juno had manuevers and that you can watch all spacecraft at any moment in time back to 1976, so that should help you.