# How did Cassini orbit Saturn with such little power?

Tags: saturn, cassini, huygens-lander

This 6-ton device entered the orbit of Saturn, and even went to the fondant module on Titan. I would like to ponder - how did they do such a thing with their small carriers? Oh yes! Gravitational maneuvers for 3 planets .. etc. And yet, does anyone have an intelligible description of what happened and how was is planned? I am interested in the speed to leave the sphere of influence of the Earth, increments during perturbation maneuvers, the sequence of entering the Saturnian orbit, Huygens' trajectory, scientific equipment on both vehicles, and their work programs. With Huygens in general mysticism - nowhere really comes across info, only common words.

Everywhere it can be seen - the lion's share of Cassini's fuel was not spent and went into the braking impulse at Saturn. Navigating Huygens with SUCH delays - finally a dark forest. (Although it is clear that everything woul roll on calculated algorithms, or was the onboard computer itself capable of analysis and decisions?

Comment: Does "power" refer to propulsive power or computing power? Spacecraft was precisely tracked and controlled from Earth: For more on maneuvers see [Unravelling Cassini's "ball of yarn" orbit around Saturn, tabulation of propulsive maneuvers?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19515/12102) and [Cassini: difference between trajectory and orbital trim maneuvers in this list?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20037/12102) and [Is Cassini's 183rd burn; some kind of engine record?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19198/12102)

Comment: and [If Cassini's final flyby of Saturn's moon Titan is the 127th Titan flyby, why is it called "T-126"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31466/12102) For "propulsive power" see [Flying fuel tanks! Which deep-space spacecraft had the largest fuel mass fraction?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23026/12102) and [Delta-v obtained from Titan by the Cassini spacecraft; just how much of a "gas tank" was it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30292/12102)