# Where was the water buildup on Cassini's narrow-angle camera system? Did it have to remain heated continuously?

Tags: water, camera, thermal, cassini

Writing [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55033/12102) led me to Wikipedia's [Cassini; launch and cruise phase (1997-2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens#Launch_and_cruise_phase_(1997%E2%80%932003)) which includes the following entries

> 0 May 2001 – During the coast phase between Jupiter and Saturn, it was noticed that "haze" became visible in the pictures taken by the narrow-angle camera of Cassini. This was first seen when a picture of the star Maia in the Pleiades was taken after a routine heating period.
>
> 23 July 2002 – In late January, a test was performed to remove the "haze" from the narrow-angle camera lens by heating it. Warming the camera to 4 degrees Celsius (39 degrees Fahrenheit) for eight days produced positive results. Later, the heating was extended to 60 days, and a picture of the star Spica showed an improvement of more than 90 percent compared to before the heating period. On 9 July, a picture showed that the removal procedure was completed successfully, which was announced on 23 July.<sup>16</sup>

<sup>16</sup> NEWS - Press Release: Cassini Camera Haze is Removed July 23, 2002 https://web.archive.org/web/20061028020201/http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/news/press-releases-02/20020723-pr-a.cfm

which includes this image that I've zoomed:

> [image: Comparison images from Cassini camera (zoomed)]
>
> Comparison images from Cassini camera
>
> Now within two years of reaching Saturn, NASA's Cassini spacecraft took test images of a star last week that reveal successful results from an extended warming treatment to remove haze that collected on a camera lens last year.
>
> The quality of the new images is virtually the same as star images taken before the haze appeared. In the most recent treatment, the camera had been warmed to 4 degrees Celsius (39 degrees Fahrenheit) for four weeks ending July 9. Four previous treatments at that temperature for varying lengths of time had already removed most of the haze. The camera usually operates at minus 90 C (minus 130 F), one of the temperatures at which test images were taken on July 9 of the star Spica.

The peak temperature reached during heating was +4 °C (normally -90 °C) so the haze was likely water, and the fact that the resulting image has a distinct annular appearance suggests it was due to somewhat monodisperse droplets on some optical surface.

**Question:** Where was the water buildup on Cassini's narrow-angle camera system? <s>Does it have to remain heated all the time now?</s> Did it have to remain heated continuously?

1. In which volume was the water trapped?
2. On which optical surfaces did it cause the problem?
3. Did the water get driven away or does the camera always have to run at +4 °C to run haze-free, or can it be operated at -90 °C?

Comment: "... all the time now?".  You are aware that the Cassini mission ended just over four years ago?

Comment: @Vince49 Sometimes I am and sometimes I'm not. It looks like today I wasn't, *but I used to be!* [Why would Cassini need to reach 64 degrees inclination before "threading the needle”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16839/12102) and [What force is bringing Cassini down into Saturn's atmosphere in another 145 days; drag, or...?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21261/12102) and [Is Cassini's 183rd burn; some kind of engine record?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19198/12102)

Comment: and [If Cassini's final flyby of Saturn's moon Titan is the 127th Titan flyby, why is it called "T-126”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31466/12102) (currently unanswered)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll be referencing the 2006 paper [*Cassini Camera Contamination Anomaly:

Experiences and Lessons Learned*](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/6.2006-5834) by Vance R. Haemmerle and James H. Gerhard of JPL.

#### Contamination (not water) inside the CCD.

> Contamination of optical instruments can occur at all stages of a mission, from instrument fabrication,
> transportation, test, integration with the spacecraft, launch and in-flight. ***Sources of contamination on the ground can
> range  from  a  fingerprint  to  contact  with  ground  equipment.  In-flight  contamination  can  result  from  loose  items
> during  launch,  ejection  of  covers,  outgassing  of  instrument  and  spacecraft  materials  such  as  water,  organics,
> silicones and propellant and the in-situ environment such as atomic oxygen in low Earth orbit or interplanetary dust
> or ring material.***

...

> A review found two  interesting  and possibly relevant  items. The first was that  the radiators of the cameras had
> been resized with thermal blankets during integration with the spacecraft and had not been subsequently baked out.
> The thermal blankets used had been baked out, but of course the tape that was used was not. Secondly, a memo was found from 1995 from the contamination engineer to the thermal blanket engineer recommending that the CCD vent
> tube be extended. Due to a personnel change this action was not taken. ***This was a suspected contamination path.***

...

> The  fact  that  a  change  occurred  at  −7°C  confirmed  to  us  that  ***the  contamination  was  indeed  close  to  the  CCD area (which was the only  area  to undergo a significant change in  temperature), perhaps in the  CCD package itself.***

...

> A meeting was held on November 16th to discuss the results [of C28]. It was decided to repeat the experiment at a slightly
> higher temperature. The only three choices to increase the temperature short of having both decontamination heaters
> on were to a) turn on the Replacement heaters, b) use the CCD performance heater fully rather than have it regulate
> the  temperature  or  c)  do  both.  The  contamination  experts  wanted  to  reach  the  temperature  at  which  the  Stardust contamination was removed but that was not possible with the possible heater combinations. ***Water was ruled out as
> a contaminant since it should have evaporated.*** There was some concern that the contamination might be evaporating
> at  the  higher  temperature  and  then  re-condensing  when  the  CCD  cooled  to  −90°C  again.  It  was  decided  to  take
> images at a halfway point to check.

#### It was thought to be on the CCD window or filter.

> Concerning the stellar images, the central peak of a star appeared normal and the intensity of the halo was only
> 1-2% the brightness of the  central peak as seen in Fig. 6. However because of spatial  extent of the halo, it actually
> contained  a  large  fraction  of  the  stellar  flux  (Fig.  7)  -  from  30%  in  the  infrared  to  70%  in  the  blue  and  ultraviolet
> (Fig. 8). The size of the halo ranged from 5 pixels in radius in the ultraviolet to up to 20 pixels in the infrared (Fig.
> 8).  Thus,  this  would  have  a  large  impact  on  the  scientific  return  of  the  NAC.  ***The  properties  of  the  point-spread
> function  were  consistent  with  the  contamination  by  very  small  particles  on  a  transmissive  surface  causing  a
> diffraction pattern in images of point source objects. The surface involved could have been the filter assembly or the
> CCD  window.***  An  interesting  side  note  was  that  Ellis  Miner,  the  Cassini  Science  Advisor,  related  that  his  early
> graduate work involved measuring diffraction patterns in an entirely different field, medicine8.

#### The contamination appeared to be gone.

> Up  to  this  point,  the  NAC  had  used  22  of
> the budgeted 57 thermal cycles for the mission.
> The risk of using a thermal cycle must be
> balanced with the diminished returns of perhaps
> a reduction in PSF width of a few hundredths of
> a pixel that another decontamination might
> accomplish.  It  was  decided  that  risk  of  further
> decontaminations outweighed the small
> possible future gains. A planned C34
> decontamination was cancelled. The images
> were  still  taken  since  it  was  too  late  to  change
> the  sequence,  but  a  real  time  command  to  turn
> on  the  heaters  was  not  sent.  Analysis  of  these
> images showed no change, as expected.
>
> A new flight rule written by J. Gerhard, not
> to allow both Level 1 and Level 2 heaters ON at
> the same time (prohibiting going to +30°C
> again) was implemented. With the start of
> Saturn  Tour,  ***no  further  decontaminations  are
> planned unless a problem reoccurs.***