# Is Vallado's Revisiting Spacetrack Report #3 still relevant today?

Tags: orbital-elements, two-line-elements, sgp4

The title pretty much sums it up. I am reading David A. Vallado's **Revisiting Spacetrack Report #3**, which was published in 2006 and includes source code for the SGP model series. I was wondering, is the code and equations still relevant today?

Comment: I think your question should be adjusted. The answer to "is it relevant" is of course yes, how could it be *irrelevant?* If you want to ask if it is the final word or if recent changes are such that there is more to be said, then better rewrite your question. TLEs and SGP4 are still backwards compatible in that you can still use old TLEs and old SGP4/SDP4 propagators and get the same good results. You can read through questions tagged with `sgp4` and `two-line-elements` to get more background and some leads on what's changing and what isn't, or leave that for answers.

Comment: See for example [Will the new “TLE format” be orbitally-mechanically better than traditional TLEs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45144/12102), and [TLE on path to be deprecated - what is 9 digit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46448/12102), and [What is/was legacy TLE ephemeris type 2? (TLE, line 1, column 63)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48697/12102)