Which LEO satellites have publicly available accurate position information?
I am working on a orbit propagation project and need accurate position information of LEO satellites. I have until now used Sentinel 3A/3B (~800 km altitude), whose ECEF coordinates I can get with a 1 day delay from the browser.dataspace.copernicus.eu web-browser. But I am looking for additional satellites, preferably at altitudes below 800 km.
Does anyone know of other satellites whose "truth" position data (i.e., <1 m accurate) is publicly available within a few days? TLE's are way too inaccurate for my purposes.
Thanks in advance!

Horizons has up to date trajectory data for a few such satellites, eg https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=hst & https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=-125544 but they're derived from TLEs.

@PM2Ring Hubble is a great candidate! But for someone "working on a orbit propagation project" the ISS's giant, complicated shape that keeps changing (solar panels busy rotating), and particularly low altitude and irregular reboosts and jettisons, the ISS' variable drag might not provide a helpful dataset. How about something completely passive with laser retroreflectors, like LAGEOS?

@uhoh Horizons has both of the LAGEOS satellites, but they're at a much higher altitude than what the OP is interested in. The body data pages are very minimal. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=lageos-1But I agree they're great test bodies for orbit propagation software.

@PM2Ring "... but they're at a much higher altitude..." uhoh! So some precision gravity mapping satellite would be good (if there are any up there at the moment). Doesn't Planet sometimes provide GPS position data from the Doves? in order to compare their propagator to TLEs? What about other satellites that use GNSS to collect data, like CYGNSS or the radio occultation satellites like the Formosats or TRITON?

Plenty of satellite operators provide "supplemental" info to Celestrak, often more accurate than the TLEs provided by the 18th. https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/supplemental/

I think this is worth a look: https://ephemerides.planet-labs.com/ - scroll down to where you see === TLEs === and === State Vectors === and then the earlier pre-amble will make more sense.

Does https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56064/37597 answer your question?  Some of the LEO laser altimetry satellites using the DORIS network (https://ids-doris.org/) routinely have post-fit position errors of only a few centimeters.  Pretty much nothing else is ever known that well, and the orbits are chosen in advance with care, but the data are public and extremely accurate.

@RyanC it does seem like almost a duplicate, and I appreciated/appreciate your answer there. But for the OP's "Which LEO satellites..." it does seem pretty challenging to find them there. If one is unfamiliar with those efforts, it could be quite challenging to find the IDs of the actual LEO satellites. I wonder instead if you might consider writing a short answer here, linking back to your excellent answer there but also finding the list the OP needs to find to identify the actual LEO satellites?

I think it's a warranted question, since the key words are a bit different to the other answers, but all the essential information has already been posted on the SE, so I would tend towards closing as a duplicate.

Thank you everyone for commenting! Very helpful! It doesn't seem like an easy task finding satellites at <600 km altitude with accurate data.
The ISS is, as mentioned by unho, too complex at this stage. Some of the suggested sources has either too large encertainties (i.e. km scale) or unknown accuracy.
Ryan C mentiones satellites using DORIS, which is indeed what I have used so far (Sentinel), so I guess my expectations have been somewhat warped by the sublime 2-3 cm accuracy.
I will continue the search!

@Frederik you are always welcome to post an answer if at some point you find something that's helpful for you. Answers benefit future readers, and usually get a couple of up votes too :-) (Once you reach 50 reputation points you can leave comments on other people's posts for example) I'm curious to hear how things turn out; good luck, and Welcome to Stack Exchange!

@Frederik there's nothing else like DORIS.  The satellites I used to operate we knew much less well, even with dedicated sensors and control over the maneuvers.  single-digit meter precision is really hard.

@RyanC accuracy is hard; isn't precision just digits? With 3 nanoseconds per meter, it seems precision is pretty accessible.

@uhoh  generally speaking, it is impossible to measure accuracy as such.  we estimate precision, and hope we're modeling it correctly.  satellites are necessarily far away and moving fast, so nailing down "true" position is complicated.  the orbits of DORIS-using satellites are estimated by a mathematical procedure that requires you to know the positions and velocities of each of the 60ish DORIS ground stations worldwide.  The ground station motion is estimated to millimeters per year, by the same calculation run backward from the orbits.  it's self-consistent, but truth remains unknowable.

@RyanC I'll give that some thought, thanks!
